# Nested scrollview inside gridview place is taking only somepart

Tags: android, gridview, nestedscrollview

I have:
1.Coordinator layout
2.appbar layout (child of Coordinator layout)
3.Collapsing toolbar layout (child of app bar)
4.NestedScrollView (child of coordinator)

**I want** to put a grid view inside `NestedScrollView` so that user can scroll over the entire screen space.

**My problem** is that currently the gridview occupies a small portion of the `NestedScrollView` and not full space of `NestedScrollView` and scrolls inside that portion,like in this image:

[image]

As you can see my gridview height is limited upto only that highlighted portion in sky blue color, i want that to occupy the entire screen space below that image(which is my Collapsing toolbar).i tried different ways but nothing works out.
my xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="196dp"
        android:background="#3f51b5"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/index"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"

        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Answer (score 15):

`GridView` already has scrolling built in, so it conflicts with a `NestedScrollView`. You should be using a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager` and `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` layout behavior in place of the `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks sir, but I 'm new to this so can you just explain with a sample code.

Answer (score 14):

well i had the same issue , the following worked for me.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fillViewport="true">
```

Comment: It solves only half of the problem - now grid fits screen height (viewport) + appbar height shift. But parameter "fillViewPort" blocks you from expanding grid height further.

Answer (score 9):

It is true, that `GridView` conflicts with the `NestedScrollView` and the correct solution would be to use the `RecyclerView`, but I needed a quick workaround with such setup and came across a solution using a custom class extending the `GridView`:
https://gist.github.com/jiahuang/2591977

Then you just have to replace your `GridView` with the custom class and set the parameter of `NestedScrollView` as in Apoorv's answer:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

Answer (score 3):

[Apoorv Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337301/nested-scrollview-inside-gridview-place-is-taking-only-somepart/37626939#37626939) helped me, but not fully. You can put a GridView inside a NestedScrollView, **but only the 1st row will show up**. You need to add the `android:fillViewport="true"` inside the NestedScrollView definition in order for everything to display properly.

But, when I scroll down, it doesn't scroll past the bottom of the screen. I have a grid with 10 rows, there are multiple rows not on screen, but I cannot scroll down to view them now.

Answer:
This worked for me now. Use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager instead of GridView. As Recycler view is compatible with Collapsing toolbar as well. And when you use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView, it works well. Everything sizes correctly, as well as scrolls correctly.

Comment: I was correcting Apoorv's answer. And I did answer his question...his problem was that currently the gridview occupies a small portion of the NestedScrollView and not full space of NestedScrollView and scrolls inside that portion. He wanted to know how to fix that. Apoorv's answer was only partially right. My answer now, as I just tested, seems to be fully correct. It helps him with his size issue as well as actually allows you to scroll properly.

Comment: Yes, using Apoorv's answer, it didn't fully scroll. Using a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager instead of GridView does allow you to fully scroll. I removed the "Any Ideas" part from the asnwer if that helps